# Double vision when adding custom answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When:

- I am editing my profile on Careers,
- And I click on "Add an answer"
- And I paste [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017587/simulating-race-conditions-in-rspec-unit-tests/2036219#2036219) into the "custom answer" field
- And I hit ENTER

Then:

- There is a brief (< 2 second) pause
- The page is redrawn, but it's a mess:

  - The answers section is missing
  - Some sections are drawn twice but not on top of each other
  - Other sections are drawn twice, on top of each other and misaligned:

[image]

If I then refresh the page, the answer has not been added.

## Networks

I am seeing the problem from two different networks.

## Systems having this problem:

### Linux

- Any of:

  - Linux 2.6.38-2-686-bigmem #1 SMP
  - Linux 3.0.0-1-686-pae #1 SMP
- Any of:

  - Iceweasel 24.3.0
  - Firefox 27.0.1
  - Chromium 32.0.1700.123 Debian jessie/sid (248368)

### A badly outdated Windows box:

- Windows XP: Version 5.1 (Build 2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.111025-1629 : Service Pack 3)
- Any of:

  - Firefox 21.0
  - Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=5cZk9l8P8EE#t=76

Comment: We couldn't have made something so trippy if we tried.

Comment: Has to be a Linux issue. I can't repro on Windows or Mac.

Comment: @Juice It reproduces on a Windows box I have access to, but it's running an unsupported version of Windows.

Comment: http://optometry.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: @WayneConrad Is this all on the same network/internet connection? What version of Windows?

Comment: @Juice Two distinct networks.  I've added the specific Windows version to the question.  I've found out we've got some VM images around here with more recent versions of Windows; I'm going to get ahold of those and see what happens.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Firefox 23 on Ubuntu 13.10, in Chrome 34 on OS X 10.9, and in IE11 on Windows 7 - so it's not platform or browser specific. It only happens when pasting a custom URL and then pressing Enter - adding an answer from the list works fine. The reason the answer doesn't get added after the "double vision" is that after pressing Enter, we load the question and there's an "Add" box you're supposed to click, though it then gets covered up by this overlay. I'm guessing nobody uses this functionality because it does seem completely broken!

Comment: The functionality does actually work - you don't need to press Enter after pasting the URL. It will be loaded automatically. To reproduce this bug though, you don't even need to paste a URL, just hit Enter in the "Or paste a link to one of your answers" box, and the screen will go craaaazy. Will take a look at this now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed.

It was all because of the ENTER keypress, which was causing a form to be submitted via AJAX. This then loaded the existing page inside itself - with hilarious consequences.

Comment: Outstanding!  Thanks for the fix, and the explanation.